# What is the exact name of the Artscroll English Siddur (Commentary) Font

Tags: prayer-book, artscroll

Does anyone know what is the exact name of the font which Artscoll uses for the English commentary at the bottom of the pages of their Interlinear Siddur (as well as the main text of many of their older seforim)?  I've also seen the same font used in R' Aryeh Kaplan's, zt"l, "Meditation and Kabbalah."

I've tried many online resources but have not successfully identified the font yet.  I suspect that it is an older font used before desktop publishing was invented and nobody ever created a digital version of it (except for Artscroll, in order that their newer siddurim have a typeface consistent with their older siddurim).

Comment: I once wanted to know the name of the font used for the title of a particular ArtScroll book. So I called ArtScroll, asked for Sheah Brander (the designer of that book), and asked him; he told me. I recommend you try something similar. Each of their books has their phone number in it and, I think, the name of the book's designer.

Comment: Is there a picture for the less Artscroll oriented?

Comment: The Typography is by CompuScribe @ ArtScroll Studios Ltd. - Brooklyn, NY

Comment: Variant of the **Hadassa** typeface : https://typographica.org/typeface-reviews/hadassah-friedlaender/